# Move i steps, turn i degrees, increase i, repeat: name of this fractal?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's consider a simple algorithm:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

scale = 0.01 # try 1
power = 1 # try 0.9, 2, 3, 4

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(master=root, width=2000, height=1500)
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.speed(speed=0)

for i in range(10000000):
    t.forward(scale*i)
    t.right(i**power)
```

Basically it moves `i` steps forward, rotates `i` degrees, increases `i` and repeats.
The algorithm produces the fractal plot :)

[image]

Does this fractal has a name? Has it been studied before?